# Conditional validation in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, customvalidator, fluentvalidation

In MVC3, there are a way to add or stop validation in a field depending on the value of a drop-drown list with JQuery? I have been trying with Fluent Validation, but with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using unobtrusive validation?  Is so, look at the html and you will see that there are some html5 attributes on your input, something like this:

```
<input name="product" id="product" data-val="true" data-val-required="Product is required" />
```

I suppose you could use jQuery to remove the `data-val` attribute and then the jQuery Validator will skip this item.

```
$("#product").data("val", false);
```

Well, that's my guess, try it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

you should use jQuery AddClass Rules

Create  jQuery Class

```
 $.validator.addClassRules({
    Req: {
        required: true
    }
});
```

Validate the Filed by checking the selected value

```
$("#Selector").blur(function () {
    var Val= $("#Selector").val();

    if (Val == "Compare to the String") {

            $("#Selector").addClass("Req");
    }
    else {
        $("#Selector").removeClass("Req");
    }
});
```

Comment: this solution should work, but is not. I'm working on other workarounds that I will post if they works.